# Typescript google maps api error handling

Tags: angular, typescript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have been trying to add error handling to my geocoding functions, but the exceptions are never triggered, this is driving me insane. Surely there must be a way to trap that RefererNotAllowedMapError?

```
private getGeocoderResponsePromise(position: google.maps.LatLng): Promise<google.maps.GeocoderResponse> {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      try {
        this.geocoder.geocode({location: position}).then(
          (result) => {
            resolve(result);
          },
          (error) => {
            if (error?.name === 'Error' && error?.message.includes('RefererNotAllowedMapError')) {
              console.log('Google Maps API error: RefererNotAllowedMapError');
              reject(new Error('RefererNotAllowedMapError: The referring URL is not allowed to access the Google Maps API.'));
            } else {
              reject(error);
            }
          }
        ).catch((error) => {
          reject(error);
        })
      } catch (error) {
        reject(error);

      }
    });
  }
```

I tried to handle error at as many level as I could think of.

Comment: I know my referer is wrong btw, I am forcing this error to make sure I handle it properly.

Comment: For now, I added a timeout and Promise.race, but I'd rather handle the error

Answer (score 0):

Try and add some console.error to make sure the error been throw not being catch by another error handlers.

```
private getGeocoderResponsePromise(position: google.maps.LatLng): Promise<google.maps.GeocoderResponse> {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    try {
      this.geocoder.geocode({ location: position })
        .then(
          (result) => {
            console.log('resolve');
            resolve(result);
          },
          (error) => {
            if (error?.name === 'Error' && error?.message.includes('RefererNotAllowedMapError')) {
              console.log('Google Maps API error: RefererNotAllowedMapError');
              reject(new Error('RefererNotAllowedMapError: The referring URL is not allowed to access the Google Maps API.'));
            } else {
              console.log('Google Maps API error: Other error');
              reject(error);
            }
          }
        )
        .catch((error) => {
          console.log('Catch block error:', error);
          reject(error);
        });
    } catch (error) {
      console.log('Try-catch block error:', error);
      reject(error);
    }
  });
}
```